# Adding Images to Tab in Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-image

I have developed a simple Android application where in i  have implemented tabs using Fragments... but i am unable to display the images for the tabs.. i have attached the source code below.. please let me know what is the error...

My Activity class TabDemoFragmentActivity.java

```
    public class TabDemoFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    /**
     * Instance variable of type {@link FragmentTabHost} 
     */
    private FragmentTabHost fragmentTabHost;

    /**
     * This is a call back method, which gets invoked 
     * when the instance of this class is created. 
     * 
     * <p>  
     *      This method is used to set the tab host and 
     *      add the tab host fragments to the screen, 
     *      which acts as a UI.
     * </P>
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        super.onCreate(bundle);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_main);

        fragmentTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        fragmentTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("DropCall Details").setIndicator("DropCall Details",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drop_call_image)).setContent(intent), QoSDropCallDetailsFragment.class, null);

        fragmentTabHost.addTab(fragmentTabHost.newTabSpec("Network Details").setIndicator("Network Details",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.network_details)), QoSNetworkDetailsFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

My XMl file

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Image is not getting displayed here.. please let me know how to display images in the tabs.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realize it is an old question but hoping someone might land on this page.  First, let me point out that FragmentTabHost is deprecated approach to adding tabs in your app. Google wants you to move to ActionTabBar to add tabs.

I had done a very similar implementation to yours and I don't see much difference. However, 2 things I can point out from your code is first, you need to make sure you copy your image to all 3 drawable folders. Second, remove the extra Framelayout(tabcontent) you have in your xml because I only had 1 Framelayout and I don't see you using the other one  in your Activity class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Here is a snippet of my Activity Class:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabFrameLayout);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_card)),
                TabActivity.ListFragment.class, null);

        mTabHost.addTab(
                mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2",
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.menu)),
                        TabActivity.ListFragments.class, null);
}
```